# Run/inject javascript on page to get the html and post it to a URL

Tags: javascript, browser

Before I used to just go to "View source" in the browser and grap all the html and post it into a form on my page. But after there have been inplemented delayed loading with ajax of some of the content I can't do this anymore.

It was not a problem doing it the old way ... but this does not work any more, since I'm missing important information.

Is it possible to somehow run a javascript in the browser, like from a bookmark shortcut or something like that. So I can grep all the html(or better yet, now filter some of the data) and then post it back to my site?

I have no idea what this is called or if its even possible.

I guess a browser extension could do this, but making for all browsers would be a pain, if this could be done with javascript.

All ideas are welcome.

Comment: Why do you want to do such thing?

Comment: Because its takes forever to have to type it manually. I'm then doing some analysis on the information with the information they have allready supplied: http://ts10.travian.com/map.sql . I'm not breaking any of there rules if thats what you are worried about.

Comment: Why don't you just make a http request in server?

Comment: Wont I have the exact same problem, since some of the sites content are loaded with javascript?

Comment: Actually in Node.JS, we can use JSDom and the javascript will be executed. An add-on for chrome or firefox could also do the job and it would be both easy(just a javascript injection).

Comment: Yes, but support for Chrome, Firefox, Internet Explorer, Opera and Safari seems a bit overkill. I had hoped for an easy way to do it, so it could work in all browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after alot of searching ... I fianlly found the answer to my own question.

Bookmarklets: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet

Which as descripbed here: http://www.learningjquery.com/2006/12/jquerify-bookmarklet let you inject jquery on the site:

Create the following as a bookmark:

```
var s=document.createElement('script');
s.setAttribute('src','https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js');
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(s);
```

Now it just extending it and fetch the information I need. Neat little trick I would say.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jquery, you could just use ajax and send the html of the body (or whatever area of the page you want) to your server.

```
$.post('url-to-send.ext', {data:$(body).html()});
```

Comment: Not asking for the javascirpt to do it, that part I can do. Its the way to do it. Like when you are on StackOverflow, you could get all "a" tags and post them to a server. Using a plugin for a browser I guess it would be easy. But can this be done with javascript and be injected/run here in some odd way I dont know of.